# insert data only when the db is first time created mongo mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Am currently working on a project with nodeJs , Mongoose , mongoDb , my problem is that i must have a user in my webApp , this user must be automatically created once Database is created which means this action happens **ONLY ONCE** , can someone help me do that?

//this is my user model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Expense = require("./expense");

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

   name : String,
   Balance : Number,
   expenses : [ Expense.schema ]

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

//and this is my mongoServer.js

````
//#region Requirements
var express=require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const cors = require("cors");
var port=9001;
var Mongo;
Mongo=mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Project',
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }
);
//#endregion


mongoose.connection
.once("open", ()=>console.log("we are connected to the db"))
.on("error", (err)=>{console.warn(err)})



//#region Configurations

var app= express();
app.use(express.json());
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000"
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const MongoApi= require('./MongoFolder/Mongo')(app, Mongo);

//#endregion


app.listen(port , function(){
    console.log('listening on port : '+port);
}); ```

Thank you in advance
````

Comment: You can check for the existence of the collection in which this user data is stored. If the collection _not exists_ insert this initial user into the collection. This will create the collection and the user document. One way to check if a collection exists is to get the list of collections in a database, search the list for a match. It is possible there is a separate API method for checking the collection's existence.

Answer (score 0):

So here is how i implemented what prasad_ has suggested in case someone needs it
it did exactly what i needed

```
//#region Requirements
var express=require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser=require('body-parser');
const cors = require("cors");
var port=9001;
var User = require("./MongoFolder/User");
var Mongo;

//#endregion


//#region Connection to Db
Mongo=mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Project',
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true
  }
);

mongoose.connection
.once("open", ()=>
{
  mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, collectionNames) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    let obj = collectionNames.find(data => data.name === 'users');
    if (obj === undefined || obj.length === 0) {

      let user = new User({ name: "Ness" , Balance: 0.00 });

      user.save();
    }
    console.log(obj);

  });
})

.on("error", (err)=>{console.warn(err)})

//#endregion

//#region Configurations

var app= express();
app.use(express.json());
var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000"
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


const MongoApi= require('./MongoFolder/Mongo')(app, Mongo);

//#endregion


app.listen(port , function(){
    console.log('listening on port : '+port);
});
```